# SharePoint Root Site name show

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint site collection. The root Web of the site collection has the URL http://intranet.com. I plan to create a user solution that will contain a Web Part. The Web Part will display the title of the root Web.

I wrote the following code segment for the Web Part.

```
SPSite currentSite = new SPSite("http://intranet.com");

Label currentTitle = new Label();

currentTitle.Text = currentSite.RootWeb.Title;
```

I added the Web Part to a page in the root Web and receive the following error message: "Web Part Error:Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred."

What should I do? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sandboxed solution you can only access the current site collection, not one specified by URL.

To get the title of the RootWeb of the current site collection use:

```
currentTitle.Text = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Title;
```

Comment: Thanks, after your reply, I tried to use SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site; which is also working fine!!